# I have libsdl2-image-dev installed via apt-get, but cmake cannot find it

Tags: cmake

I just installed libsdl2-image-dev via apt-get, and here is the result of my "dpkg -L libsdl2-image-dev" command:

```
$ dpkg -L libsdl2-image-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev/examples
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev/examples/showimage.c
/usr/include
/usr/include/SDL2
/usr/include/SDL2/SDL_image.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/SDL2_image.pc
/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-image-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so
```

However, the "find_package(SDL2_IMAGE REQUIRED)" in cmake complains that:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSDL2_IMAGE.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "SDL2_IMAGE", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SDL2_IMAGE" with
  any of the following names:

    SDL2_IMAGEConfig.cmake
    sdl2_image-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SDL2_IMAGE" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SDL2_IMAGE_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "SDL2_IMAGE" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You have none of the files listed in the error message (`FindSDL2_IMAGE.cmake`, `SDL2_IMAGEConfig.cmake` or `sdl2_image-config.cmake`). If you follow [that blog](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/07/04/using-sdl2-image-with-cmake/), then it tells about file `FindSDL2_IMAGE.cmake`, which you have to create and make it searchable via `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable.

Comment: Solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**FOR x64 LINUX**

install sdl2 image lib

```sh
apt install libsdl2-image-dev
```

Create a file in cmake configs folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/sdl2_image/sdl2_image-config.cmake`

and put this in it

```
set(prefix "/usr") 
set(exec_prefix "${prefix}")
set(libdir "${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")
set(SDL2_IMAGE_PREFIX "/usr")
set(SDL2_IMAGE_EXEC_PREFIX "/usr")
set(SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS "${prefix}/include/SDL2_image")
set(SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES "-lSDL2_image")
```

Then add to `CMakeLists.txt` following

```
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(app SDL2_image)
```